# Export theme and its associated layers in xml file in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

I was trying to export all themes and its corresponding layers information through PyQGIS so that  `xml` can be read later .There is method in `Class: QgsMapThemeCollection, writeXml(self, doc: QDomDocument)` but cannot able to write into xml file.

Below code has been tried but cannot able to write.

```
doc = QDomDocument()
qgsl = QgsProject.instance()
mTC = qgsl.mapThemesCollection()
mTs = mTC.mapThemes()
mTc.writeXml(doc)
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
doc = QDomDocument()
qgsl = QgsProject.instance()
mTC = qgsl.mapThemeCollection() # and *not* mapThemesCollection()
mTs = mTC.mapThemes()
mTC.writeXml(doc) # note the variable name change
```

Comment: thanks for reply.Can you please share the way to import generated xml file and location of stored xml file.