# Store QGIS map themes (to XML)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt

I would like to store QGIS Map themes to be used later. In my workflow, I use a plugin which imports many (grouped) layers. Each layer contains several styles that I can switch between. I want to switch some of the styles of the layers, and then store these settings as a Map Theme. This works great, the problem is that next time I use the same plugin (in a new QGIS project), I don't have the Map Themes available as they are not stored.

I thought I found a solution to store the Map Themes using PyQGIS, but I can't get it to work.
I found this thread: [Export theme and its associated layers in xml file in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387794/export-theme-and-its-associated-layers-in-xml-file-in-pyqgis)

I add a Map Theme, and then run the following code

```
doc = QDomDocument()
mapThemesCollection = QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection()
print(mapThemesCollection.mapThemes()) # I see the names of my themes printed
mapThemesCollection.writeXml(doc)
```

The `doc` QDomDocument still seems to be empty since `doc.toString()` prints an empty string. Also, how do I save this as an XML file to be read later with `mapThemesCollection.readXml(doc)`

If there are other solutions to re-use themes within different projects I am also glad to hear about them.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `qgis` child element to your `QDomDocument`  according to the [source code](https://qgis.org/api/qgsmapthemecollection_8cpp_source.html#l00656)

```py
doc = QDomDocument()
doc.appendChild(doc.createElement('qgis'))
mapThemesCollection = QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection()
mapThemesCollection.writeXml(doc)
print(doc.toString())
```

To read it in a new `QDomDocument`

```
doc1 = QDomDocument()
print(doc1.setContent(your_xml_string))
print(doc1.toString())
```

To read or write file, you can either choose Python `open` method or Qt/PyQt `QFile`

Comment: Thank you, this answered the technical part of my question. I am now able to view the XML of the Map Themes. Unfortunately, I found out that layers are stored with their id, which is different every time I load the layers from different files. I'm now trying to solve my problem by recreating the Map Themes using PyQGIS. Unfortunately, I am not able to set the style of layers (only create state from current), nor if groups are checked or not (MapThemeRecord.hasCheckedStateInfo() is not available in python bindings). Anyone knows a way to store style, checked & collapsed of groups and layers?

Comment: It's more than one question. The website is for Q&A with one focus. Ask another question with only one question